# How to switch input fields with keyboard keys in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input-field

How can I jump from one input field to another input field with the arrow keys on the keyboard?

This is my attempt:

```js
document.onkeydown = (function(e1){
    if (e1.which == 39) { 
       F2();
    }
});

document.onkeydown = (function(e2){
    if (e2.which == 37) { 
       F1();
    }
});

function F1() {
  document.getElementById("right").focus();
  document.getElementById("left").blur();
}

function F2() {
  document.getElementById("right").blur();  
  document.getElementById("left").focus();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="right">
<input type="text" id="left">
```

Comment: `Tab` and `Shift+Tab` are the standard shortcuts for moving between focusable elements such as inputs. This is well-known behavior that browsers implement by default, no JavaScript required. Is there any special reason you want to use non-standard shortcuts for this?

Comment: I find it stupid: these are text boxes, using the arrows can only complicate the entry, ex :  when you want to change back a wrong letters in an input

Comment: @LionelRowe Yes, because Shift+Tab is not working.

Comment: @SavePain If `Shift+Tab` isn’t working, that’s either a) because you have another event listener that’s conflicting with it (for example with `event.preventDefault()`), b) because of conflicting third-party software, or c) because your keyboard is broken. I'd recommend trying to troubleshoot those problems first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your example sets the first event handler, then overwrites it with the next.

to do it (using the method your using) you need to add both events to one handler.

```
document.onkeydown = (function(e){
    if (e.which == 39) { 
       F2();
    }
    if (e.which == 37) { 
       F1();
    }
});

function F1() {
  document.getElementById("right").focus();
  document.getElementById("left").blur();
}

function F2() {
  document.getElementById("right").blur();  
  document.getElementById("left").focus();
}
```

a better way would be to use something like:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) { event code });
```

so you dont overwrite any existing event handlers

Comment: Thank you!, It actually works, if you replace e2.which with e1.which